# Why a command prompt comes out then disappear after I click defrag in search in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, defragment

I did exactly the same in the pic:

[image: Screenshot from Windows 8 Start screen]

then I saw a quick command prompt come out and it did something quickly, then it is closed by itself. I installed the smart defrag 2, used it then uninstalled it, is that because the smart defrag 2 changed something?

Comment: Use dfrgui or search Settings instead of Apps.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. `defrag` is a name of a command line tool. Try it yourself:

1. Open the Start screen and type `cmd`.
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `defrag` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It will say "The parameter is incorrect" (because it expected one and you haven't provided it) and print help. It's quite long so you have to scroll, or if you're a command line purist you can try again with `defrag | more` and read it page by page.

The `defrag` tool was used in XP as a workaround for one of grahical defragmenter's limitations - it wouldn't run if you had less than 15% of free disk space. `defrag` let you bypass that limitation by using the `-f` switch. The one provided with Windows 7 doesn't seem to accept that switch anymore (or it doesn't list it).